# Analog watch simulation

Tags: c#, performance, simulation, monogame

I wrote an analog watch simulation in C# and Monogame as exercise.

The application consists of a background texture. On top of that I have the hour-, minute- and second hand.

The program gets its time from DateTime.Now.

The second hand rotates by multiplying the seconds with 1/60 of a total lap in radians.

It's the same with the minute hand and hour hand.

Source code:

```
class Clock
{
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    // Textures
    public Texture2D CaseBack;
    public Texture2D HourHand;
    public Texture2D MinuteHand;
    public Texture2D SecondHand;

    Vector2 center = new Vector2(63, 63); // Center of watch

    // Gets called 60 times/second
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime) 
    {
        hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        minutes = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;
    }

    // Gets called 60 times/second
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        // Background/Case back
        spriteBatch.Draw(CaseBack, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

        // Second hand
        spriteBatch.Draw(SecondHand, center, null, null, new Vector2(3, 50),
            ((float)seconds*(float)Math.PI*2 / 60),
            // This is the rotation. Works by multiplying Seconds with a 1/60 of a "circle's angle".
            null, Color.White, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        // Minute hand - basically the same, but with minutes
        spriteBatch.Draw(MinuteHand, center, null, null, new Vector2(3, 40),
            ((float)minutes * (float)Math.PI * 2 / 60),
            null, Color.White, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        // Hour hand - same here
        spriteBatch.Draw(HourHand, center, null,null, new Vector2(4, 30),
            ((float)hour * (float)Math.PI * 2 / 12),
            null, Color.White, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't repeat yourself

The step of drawing the hour, minute, second hands are all very similar.
It would be good to use a helper function:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D hand, int value, Vector2 vector2, float coef)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(hand, center, null, null, vector2,
        value * Math.PI * coef,
        null, Color.White, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

#### Visibility

Since the `hour`, `minutes`, `seconds` should not be visible outside the class,
it would be good to make them explicitly `private`.
(Thanks [@Maxim](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/143354/maxim) for the clarification that the default access modifier is actually `private`.)

Comment: `hour`, `minutes`, `seconds` already are private since it is the default access modifier for a class member. But in my opinion it is much more clear if an access modifier is specified explicitly.